# How to display the last 4 digits of the credit card used for a Craft Commerce purchase

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'd like to display the last 4 digits of the credit card used for a purchase in a front-end template. It appears the data is in the db in the `craft_commerce_transactions` table `reference` column in JSON format.

```
{
    "approvalCode":"PNRABL",
    "transId":"60007205645",
    "card": {
        "number":"1234",
        "expiry":"112318"
    }
}
```

Is there a method supported by Craft Commerce to display this data in a users account area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're referring to displaying this in the Control Panel somewhere or on the front-end of a site in a user account area.

Assuming it's on the front-end of a site and you've already got a reference to the order, it'd be something like:

```
{# Grab an order #}
{% set order = craft.commerce.orders.id(15).first() %}

{% if order %}
    {% Grab all of it's transactions %}
    {% set transactions = order.getTransactions() %}

    {# Loop through all of them looking for the one(s) you're interested in on this order.  Here, we just grab the first. #}
    {% set transaction = transactions[0] %}

    {# Output the reference #}
    {{ transaction.reference }}
{% endif %}
```

Keep in mind that the reference value is a response that comes back directly from the particular payment gateway, so it may or may not even be JSON, much less include the last 4 digits of a credit card number.  If it is JSON, XML, etc. then you'll need to parse that value looking for where they save the last 4 digits.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to do so in a front-end template so good example. Kinda messy for something that seems to be so common in online e-commerce experiences.

Comment: This does seem like a common enough requirement that it could be helpful to have a method on the Transaction Model `{{ transaction.last4digits() }}` that does the gateway-specific logic and returns null if a gateway doesn't provide those digits.

Comment: Is this still the only way to achieve this even with Commerce 3?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to Brad's would be to save the four digits to a field on the order at the time of the transaction...would make for easier retrieval later.  We do this with a fraud score our one of our gateways gives us...

```
    // Save the Beagle Anti-Fraud Score to the order
    craft()->on('commerce_transactions.onSaveTransaction', function ($event)
    {

            $transaction = $event->params['transaction'];
            $order = $transaction->order;

            // Transactions are saved before responses too....
            if($transaction->response){
                BusinessLogicPlugin::log($transaction->response);

                if (array_key_exists("BeagleScore",$transaction->response)){
                    $score = (string) $transaction->response['BeagleScore'];
                    BusinessLogicPlugin::log("Beagle score found: $score");
                    $order->setContentFromPost(["beagleScore"=>$score]);
                    craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($order);
                }
            }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jeremy. It does seem like a gateway-specific plugin or macro may be handy to make this feel less tedious.